# Socket programming in iphone

Tags: iphone, networking

I want to send/receice some data to remote machine within network.
I have referred chatty application but it is broadcasting the service but i need to establish one is to one connection.
how can i set sockets for sending and receiving data in iphone?
does any one have any idea? i am new to network programming please help me about this.

Regards,
Sanket

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about CFNetwork, then I recommend: Zdziarski's **[iPhone SDK Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043GXMSE) - Chapter 7**

There are complete explanation of sockets ;)